# Multiple router-views, activated 1 at a time

Tags: javascript, vue.js, components, vue-component, vue-router

Ok so I have a component, machine, inside that component I have a component called gear being imported, I use gear three times in a div, the gear component has a button that when pressed should display that gear components details by displaying a geardetails component where the gear component was displayed. Geardetails also has a button that should hide it and show gear component again.

As it is right now I am using 3 router-view to display the gear components but when I click the button it changes all 3 gear components to geardetails components instead of just the one I clicked.

In my router file the gear and geardetails are pathed as children to the machine component. The buttons' function is just pushing the path to geardetails/gear.

Any advice is welcome, I'm still a beginner with vue so please be kind. :)

Comment: my advice - you probably need to change the code because you are probably doing *something wrong™* now

Comment: `I am using 3 router-view` well, there's your problem - you can only be in one route at a time